# Out of range percentile values using percentile.exc in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentile

I am new to PowerBi and would need some help figuring out how to make the percentile.exc function work (I cannot use percentile.inc).

I systematically receive the following error: The percentile value should be in the range 1/(N+1)..N/(N+1) inclusive, where N is the number of data values.

The objective of this code is to compute the 3months rolling 90th percentile of a given ratio in another calculated column.

I would be very grateful for any help!

This is what I have come with up so far:

```
3MonthsRolling_90thPercentile= 
VAR current_date = Table1[Date]
VAR k = 0.9
VAR NumValues =
COUNT (Table1[Ratio] )
VAR LowerBound = 1 / ( NumValues + 1 )
VAR UpperBound = NumValues / ( NumValues + 1 )

RETURN
CALCULATE (
IF (AND ( PERCENTILE.EXC ( Table1[Ratio],0.9) >= LowerBound, PERCENTILE.EXC (Table1[Ratio],0.9) <= UpperBound ),PERCENTILE.EXC ( Table1[Ratio],0.9), BLANK()),
FILTER (
ALL (Table1 ),
Table1[Date]
>= DATE ( YEAR ( current_date ), MONTH ( current_date ) - 3, DAY ( current_date ) )
&& Table1[Date] <= current_date
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `NumValues` is less than 9 in, then 0.9 is above your upper bound `NumValues / ( NumVales + 1 )`, so `PERCENTILE.EXC ( Table1[Ratio], 0.9 )` will throw an error.

I think your measure would make more sense as follows:

```
3MonthsRolling_90thPercentile =
VAR current_date = Table1[Date]
VAR DateFiltered =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Table1 ),
        Table1[Date]
            >= DATE (
                   YEAR ( current_date ),
                   MONTH ( current_date ) - 3,
                   DAY ( current_date )
               )
            && Table1[Date] <= current_date
    )
VAR k = 0.9
VAR NumValues = CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Table1[Ratio] ), DateFiltered )
VAR LowerBound = 1 / ( NumValues + 1 )
VAR UpperBound = NumValues / ( NumValues + 1 )
RETURN
    IF (
        AND ( k >= LowerBound, k <= UpperBound ),
        CALCULATE ( PERCENTILE.EXC ( Table1[Ratio], k ), DateFiltered )
    )
```

Note that I'm comparing `k` to the bounds rather than the `k`-percentile.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I see how it makes more sense, however when I changed it, I still got the error: "The percentile value should be in the range 1/(N+1)..N/(N+1) inclusive, where N is the number of data values." I cannot share the data sadly as it is my company's ..

Comment: Hmm. I think the problem might be that your `NumValues` variable might be different than what's actually being used inside CALCULATE since that is filtering down to a particular date range which probably has fewer values than the whole table. I'll edit my answer.